# How to calculate the dissipated energy on a wire as a function of x

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, induction, electromagnetic-induction

I am having some trouble solving this exercise, I would really appreciate if you could help me. Sorry if this has been asked before, I am new to the site and don't understand how things work here very well. Also, I hastily translated the exercise to English so ask and I'll try to clarify things if something isn't clear enough.

[image]

"A constant current I flows through a long straight wire. There is a U shaped wire below it with resistance per unit lenght r. On the U shaped wire there is a rod moving to the right at a constant speed v. Assuming that at t=0 the wire is at position x=0 find the expression for the energy dissipated on the wire for when the wire has moved a distance x."

From Faraday's law I get the value for the induced emf:
$$
\varepsilon= \int (\vec{v}\times\vec{B})\cdot d\vec{l}\Rightarrow \varepsilon =-vBL
$$

Dividing it by the resistance I get the current in the wire:
$$
I=\varepsilon/R, r=R/L \Rightarrow 
I=-\frac{vB}{r}
$$
Then I found the magnetic field using Amepere's law:
$$
\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\mu_{0}I}{2\pi y}dy=\frac{\mu_{0}I}{2\pi}ln(b/a)
$$

I used that to calculate the power P:
$$
P=\epsilon I=\frac{v^2\mu^2_{0}I^2L}{r4\pi^2}ln^2(b/a)
$$

I know that Energy is equal to P*t. But I don't see the time dependency in the variables in the expression for the power and as a result I don't know how to integrate it to get the expression energy. How should I continue?

Answer (score 2):

When calculating the electric field, you need to take into account that $B$ is a function of $l$ so your first result is incorrect. The voltage should result in a current over the u-shaped cable. The length and therefore the resistance of that changes as a function of time. Combine those two and you have the power as function of time. Integrating over this gives energy.